# I'm facing error when starting startWeblogic sh

Tags: weblogic12c, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have successfully installed and configured weblogic server but when I run `startWeblogic.sh` file i'm facing error.

```
 <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.AssertionError: nobody!=oradwbi
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.t3.srvr.BootService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.server.PartitionRuntimeBuilderService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.server.PartitionRuntimeBuilderService

A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.AssertionError: nobody!=oradwbi
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.t3.srvr.BootService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.server.PartitionRuntimeBuilderService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.server.PartitionRuntimeBuilderService
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue follow below steps

1. Take backup of config.xml and remove below line

post-bind-gid-enabled = true tag

2. Restart the Admin server by clearing tmp and cache folders.